# Reverse SSH and SSH keys

Tags: linux, ssh

**Scenario**

VPS out in the Internet. Internal machine behind company network.

**Goal**

Have **$internal_machine** connect to **$VPS**; I login to **$VPS** and connect to **$internal_machine** SSH session that will be local in **$VPS**.

**Keys**

**$VPS** contains the public SSH block in .authorized_hosts. **$internal_machine** is connecting with the private key to **$VPS**

**Code**

On **$internal_machine**:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -i .ssh/KEY -R 2048:localhost:22 vps.internet.net
```

Connection is established. Prompt in **$internal_machine** changes to **$VPS** prompt.

On $VPS:

```
ssh -p 2048 localhost
```

Error:

```
ubuntu@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've also tried connecting, in **$VPS**, specifying the keys with -i, doesn't work either.

Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 0):

The key that needs to be used is the one originally configured to login to $VPS.